# How to embed the base.js file of libphonenumber into iOS project

Tags: ios

I want to use the **libphonenumber** in my iPhone project.

For the *demo.html* (javascript branch), the base.js is a remote file.

I hope the base.js can be embeded into my project as a local file.

from:

```
<script src="http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
```

change to:

```
 <script src="base.js">
```

but when I download the base.js and put it into my project. the *demo.html* is not work anymore.

So how can I use the base.js?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should be `<script src="base.js" />`